# Getting error with html to pdf converter(pdfkit) in local windows 10 machine

Tags: django, pdfkit, xvfb

"cmd=['Xvfb', '-help']\nOSError=[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified\nProgram install error! "

I'm getting this error while converting from HTML to pdf in windows10
I have installed wkhtmltopdf0.9.9 in my windows10
configured the wkhtmltopdf path in my project and also in environment variable.

Comment: That package requires `Xvfd` which is not supported on windows

Answer (score 0):

Try Re-Installing wkhtmltopdf after complete uninstall from the system.